# How to split group result into unlimited individual columns

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

If I have a table:

```
id  tstamp  x   y
-----------------
1   111     1   A
2   111     2   B
3   111     3   C
4   222     1   D
5   222     2   E
6   222     3   F
7   333     1   G
8   333     2   H
9   333     3   I
... nnn     ... ...
```

How can I split it into the following, where the number of columns is dependent on a range of tstamp?

```
x   y111    y222    y333    ynnn
----------------------------------
1   A       D       G       ...
2   B       E       H       ...
3   C       F       I       ...
```

It seems fundamentally simple, but I can't find any relevant example or API?  There's a good 10 or so similar questions but they all deal with string handling, csv, xml???

I imagine it would be pretty straight forward to do in c# or another scripting language, but I would expect it should be an easy thing in sql?

Comment: The answers you saw are probably correct. Dynamic PIVOT is what you are looking for and yes it is a little involved.

Comment: Thanks, keyword Pivot... :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to construct column values of tstamp for PIVOT and use dynamic query

```
DECLARE @cols NVARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT  @cols = STUFF(( SELECT DISTINCT TOP 100 PERCENT
                                '],[' + tstamp
                        FROM    Table1 
                        ORDER BY '],[' + tstamp
                        FOR XML PATH('')
                      ), 1, 2, '') + ']'


DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(4000)
SET @query = N'SELECT x, '+
@cols +'
FROM
(SELECT  x, y, tstamp
FROM    Table1 
) p
PIVOT
(
MAX(y)
FOR tstamp IN
( '+
@cols +' )
) AS pvt
'

exec sp_executesql @query
```